# List builder versus for loops

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I've got a piece of code that -- works! So, not asking for debug help.

I'm three days into learning date and mostly positive, but sometimes hard to find working code examples of things i'm trying to do. So, lots of trial and error. My best advice is to set the background color on every widget to something bold (yellow, green, blue) to help troubleshoot design/layout issues.

But, I read a lot about how to implement something like this: retrieve json data from an API, iterate through it to create a dynamic list of widgets using Future<>. My example is pure flutter web at this time.

The problem is - many sites suggested using List Builder also and for the life of me I could not get it to work. It kept overflowing the bottom of the browser and I could not find any way to extend it. I used a "for Model in List" loop and it worked fine.

So, my question is - if i give you working code, can you suggest a better approach/implementation?

```dart
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<Menurender>>(
        future: fetchMenu(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.none &&
              snapshot.hasData == null) {
            //print('project snapshot data is: ${projectSnap.data}');
            return Container();
          }
          return Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            //color: Colors.yellow,
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .80,
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: Column(children: [
                    for (Menurender menu in snapshot.data)
                      Column(children: <Widget>[
                        Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            //SizedBox(width: 60),
                            Text(
                              '${menu.weekDayFull}',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Color(0xff444444),
                                  fontSize: 32,
                                  letterSpacing: 2,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                  fontFamily: 'Fira Sans'),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            //SizedBox(width: 60),
                            Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text(
                                  '${menu.dayOfMonth} ${menu.monthFull}',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Color(0xff333333),
                                      fontSize: 14,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                      fontFamily: 'Fira Sans'),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                                child: Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Padding(
                                  padding:
                                      const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 0, 0, 0),
                                  child: Container(
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        //color: Colors.red,
                                        border: Border(
                                      bottom: BorderSide(
                                          color: Color(0xff4A4A4A4A)),
                                    )),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ))
                          ],
                        )
                      ])
                  ])),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        });
  }
```

The actual code working is here so you can see what i'm trying to accomplish:
my test build in progress:
https://flavorboxstorage.z23.web.core.windows.net/#/

actual company wordpress site:
https://www.flavorboxsaigon.com/

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Comment: i'm still trying to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: i'm getting errors

Comment: Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 98464 pixels on the right.
Another exception was thrown: Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.
Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: org-dartlang-app:///packages/flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1694:12
Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: org-dartlang-app:///packages/flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1694:12
Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: org-dartlang-app:///packages/flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1694:12

Comment: ive figured out the unbounded height. the renderflex overflowing was an error on my for loop also. so troubleshooting the assertion failed error now

Comment: doesn't work. it's back to the same problem i had before. i'm using the most recent build of flutter.

Comment: two errors: 1) length of snapshot is always null

Comment: 2) size missing on axis direction down. nothing i can ever do fixes it.

Comment: ssertion failed: org-dartlang-app:///packages/flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1725:16
constraints.hasBoundedWidth
is not true

The relevant error-causing widget was:
ListView

Comment: relayoutBoundary=up22 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE:
needs compositing
creator: ShrinkWrappingViewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#15f10] ← Semantics ← _PointerListener ←
Listener ← _GestureSemantics ←
RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey<RawGestureDetectorState>#d7720] ← _PointerListener ← Listener
← _ScrollableScope ← _ScrollSemantics-[GlobalKey#4034e] ← RepaintBoundary ← ⋯
parentData: <none> (can use size)
constraints: BoxConstraints(unconstrained)
size: MISSING
axisDirection: down

Answer (score 2):

Writing a `for` loop inside your widget tree makes life difficult for Flutter when rebuilding widgets and might affect your performance. You should be able to just use a ListView.builder like this:

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            //SizedBox(width: 60),
            Text(
              '${snapshot.data[index].weekDayFull}',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Color(0xff444444),
                fontSize: 32,
                letterSpacing: 2,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                fontFamily: 'Fira Sans'
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            //SizedBox(width: 60),
            Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  '${snapshot.data[index].dayOfMonth} ${snapshot.data[index].monthFull}',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xff333333),
                    fontSize: 14,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                    fontFamily: 'Fira Sans'
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 0, 0, 0),
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        //color: Colors.red,
                        border: Border(
                          bottom: BorderSide(
                            color: Color(0xff4A4A4A4A)
                          ),
                        )
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            )
          ],
        )
      ]
    );
  }
)
```

Answer (score -2):

if you want to use for loop you can just do it like this

```
ListView(
   children: <Widget>[
     for(var x=0; x<snapshot.data.length;x++)
     Container(
        child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                    Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        //SizedBox(width: 60),
                        Text(
                          '${menu.weekDayFull}',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Color(0xff444444),
                              fontSize: 32,
                              letterSpacing: 2,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                              fontFamily: 'Fira Sans'),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        //SizedBox(width: 60),
                        Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(
                              '${menu.dayOfMonth} ${menu.monthFull}',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Color(0xff333333),
                                  fontSize: 14,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                  fontFamily: 'Fira Sans'),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                            child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Padding(
                              padding:
                                  const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 0, 0, 0),
                              child: Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    //color: Colors.red,
                                    border: Border(
                                  bottom: BorderSide(
                                      color: Color(0xff4A4A4A4A)),
                                )),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ))
     )
   ]
)
```

if you want ListView.builder

```
ListView.builder(
   itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
   itemBuilder: (context, index){
       return Container(
        child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                    Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        //SizedBox(width: 60),
                        Text(
                          '${menu.weekDayFull}',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Color(0xff444444),
                              fontSize: 32,
                              letterSpacing: 2,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                              fontFamily: 'Fira Sans'),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        //SizedBox(width: 60),
                        Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(
                              '${menu.dayOfMonth} ${menu.monthFull}',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Color(0xff333333),
                                  fontSize: 14,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                  fontFamily: 'Fira Sans'),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                            child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Padding(
                              padding:
                                  const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 0, 0, 0),
                              child: Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    //color: Colors.red,
                                    border: Border(
                                  bottom: BorderSide(
                                      color: Color(0xff4A4A4A4A)),
                                )),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ))
     )
   ]
);
   }
)
```

but for me I make use of map as child of Listview